# Process modeling with fine-grained notions of location

Tags: concurrency, process-algebra, formal-modeling

Is anyone aware of any process algebraic (or related) formalisms that capture fine-grained location information?  I'm familiar with ambients and bigraphs, which obviously have a location model, but what about attempts to model more concrete location information, such that the location of some agent is expressed within some (real or virtual) coordinate space?

It seems to me that it would be possible to take some existing formalism and enrich it with constructs to model location at some appropriate level of abstraction, but I would hate to reinvent the wheel needlessly if this is reminiscent of previous efforts.

As background, the application domain is essentially biological modeling where the traditional notions of location used in this domain to govern where interactions can occur are not fine-grained enough to capture the properties of interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Processes in Space](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~pg/papers/geometric.pdf) by Luca Cardelli and Philippa Gardner is one paper in this direction. It specified a process algebra for describing the evolution of 3D structures.

Comment: Fantastic reference and appears to be exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks a bunch :)